# Qimage setPixel with openmp parallel for doesn't work

Tags: c++, qt, parallel-processing, openmp, qimage

The code works without parallelism, but when I add pragma omp parallel, it doesn't work. Furthermore, the code works perfectly with pragma omp parallel if I don't add setPixel. So, I would like to know why the parallelism doesn't work properly and exits the program with code 255 when I try to set pixel in the new image. This code wants to change an image doing two loops to change every pixel using a Gauss vector. If something can't be understood I'll solve it inmediately.

```
for (h = 0; h < height; h++){
  QRgb* row = (QRgb*) result->scanLine(h);

  //#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic) num_threads(cores) private (j, auxazul, auxrojo, auxverde) reduction(+:red,green,blue)
  for (w = 0; w < width; w++) {
      red=green=blue=0;

      minj = max((M-w),0);
      supj = min((width+M-w),N);
      for (j=minj; j<supj; j++){
          auxazul = azul [w-M+j][h];
          auxrojo = rojo [w-M+j][h];
          auxverde = verde [w-M+j][h];

          red += vectorGauss[j]*auxrojo;
          green += vectorGauss[j]*auxverde;
          blue += vectorGauss[j]*auxazul;
      }

      red /= 256; green /= 256; blue /= 256;
      //result->setPixel(w,h,QColor(red,green,blue).rgba());
      row[w] = QColor(red,green,blue).rgba();
  }
```

Comment: From the help centre (which you were pointed at when you joined us, and which I expect you read from start to finish :-) ): *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.*  Your question lacks most of what is required to make it a good question.

Comment: why would you want to use setpixel to fill an entire image in the first place? it is a very slow operation.

Comment: I have to do in this way, it's an exercise

Comment: Where is `setPixel()` documented to be thread-safe?  Without that guarantee, you can't make any predictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside the comment that setPixel is slow and not thread safe, you currently have a race condition when writing the result

```
 row[w] = QColor(red,green,blue).rgba();
```

Your code is slow in the first place because you are accessing your color matrices in a memory inefficient way. Pumping threads will make this part worse. Given that you loop on each scanline, you would like to have the transposee of your color matrices. Which allow you to do :

```
for (h = 0; h < height; h++){
  QRgb* row = (QRgb*) result->scanLine(h);

  auto azulscan = azul [h];
  auto rojoscan = rojo [h];
  auto verdescan = verde [h];

  for (w = 0; w < width; w++) {
      red=green=blue=0;
      minj = max((M-w),0);
      supj = min((width+M-w),N);
      for (j=minj; j<supj; j++){
          auto auxazul = azulscan [w-M+j];
          auto  auxrojo = rojoscan [w-M+j];
          auto auxverde = verdescan [w-M+j];

          red += vectorGauss[j]*auxrojo;
          green += vectorGauss[j]*auxverde;
          blue += vectorGauss[j]*auxazul;
      }
      row[w] = QColor(red,green,blue).rgba();
  }
```

}

I dont know openmp well but you want to have a single thread per scanline, so your parallel loop need to be above the first loop. Something like

```
#pragma omp parallel for whatever
for (h = 0; h < height; h++){
  QRgb* row;

  #pragma omp critical
  {
    row = = (QRgb*) result->scanLine(h);
  }

  ....
```

}

Another point. You can use [std::inner_product](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inner_product) to compute the color value in a single line once you have the transpose of the color inputs.

```
green = std::inner_product(&vectorGauss[minj], &vectorGauss[supj-1]+1, &verdescan[w-M+jmin], &verdescan[w-M+supj]+1)
```

Comment: Transpose your color inputs beforehand.

Comment: Thanks, it's perfect I have changed some things and it works properly

Answer (score 1):

QImage::setPixel is not thread safe, since it calls the *detach()* method (have a look at the official documentation [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#setPixel)). Remember QImage uses *implicit sharing*.

Besides, *setPixel()* is **extremely slow**. If you are seeking performance (as someone usually do when dealing with parallel implementations), that's not the best way to go.

Using *scanLine()* as you already do in the example provided is the correct way of doing it.

Comment: Using scanLine() doesn't solve the problem of parallelism, I have the same error.

Comment: Citing your own comment: "... if I don't use setPixel or I try to change **using scanLine the parallelism works properly**.". Now I'm confused.... We are willing to help here but could you please make some efforts to make your question to make it **clear** please?

Comment: OK, I'm going to delete it, if I use scanLine or setPixel the parallelism doesn't work. I'm sorry about my English. So, I would like to know if this code can use pragma omp parallel or not.

Comment: Start by explaining what you mean by "it doesn't work". Does it crash? If yes, where exactly? Does it throw any error? Is the output imagr different from what you expect? Describe in details what happens, what you did already and what is the expected result.

Comment: Yes, it crash with an error 255. It crashes at the end of the for loop when I use setPixel() or scanLine() and pragma omp parallel at the same time. The output image is correct without using pragma omp parallel. Furthermore, the first part of the code (it's not posted here) is parallelised and it works properly.