# OpenMP Fractal Generator

Tags: c++, qt, openmp, multicore, fractals

I've been trying to create an openMP variant of the julia set, but I'm unable to create a coherent image when running more than one thread, I've been trying to solve what looks like a race condition but cannot find the error. 
The offending output looks like the required output along with "scanlines" across the entirety of the picture.

I've attached the code as well if its not clear enough.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <omp.h>
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QElapsedTimer>
using namespace std;



double newReal(int x, int imageWidth){
    return 1.5*(x - imageWidth / 2)/(0.5 * imageWidth);
}

double newImaginary(int y, int imageHeight){
    return (y - imageHeight / 2) / (0.5 * imageHeight);
}

int julia(double& newReal, double& newImaginary, double& oldReal, double& oldImaginary, double cRe, double cIm,int maxIterations){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < maxIterations; i++){
      oldReal = newReal;
      oldImaginary = newImaginary;
      newReal = oldReal * oldReal - oldImaginary * oldImaginary + cRe;
      newImaginary = 2 * oldReal * oldImaginary + cIm;
      if((newReal * newReal + newImaginary * newImaginary) > 4) break;
    }
    return i;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fnum=atoi(argv[1]);
    int numThr=atoi(argv[2]);
//    int imageHeight=atoi(argv[3]);
//    int imageWidth=atoi(arg[4]);
//    int maxIterations=atoi(argv[5]);
//    double cRe=atof(argv[3]);
//    double cIm=atof(argv[4]);
    //double cRe, cIm;
    int imageWidth=10000, imageHeight=10000, maxIterations=3000;
    double newRe, newIm, oldRe, oldIm,cRe,cIm;
    cRe = -0.7;
    cIm = 0.27015;
    string fname;
    QElapsedTimer time;
    QImage img(imageHeight, imageWidth, QImage::Format_RGB888);//Qimagetesting
    img.fill(QColor(Qt::black).rgb());//Qimagetesting
    time.start();
    int i,x,y;
    int r, gr, b;
#pragma omp parallel for shared(imageHeight,imageWidth,newRe,newIm) private(x,y,i) num_threads(3)
        for(y = 0; y < imageHeight; y++)
        {
            for(x = 0; x < imageWidth; x++)
            {
                newRe = newReal(x,imageWidth);
                newIm = newImaginary(y,imageHeight);
                i= julia(newRe, newIm, oldRe, oldIm, cRe, cIm, maxIterations);

                r = (3*i % 256);
                gr = (2*(int)sqrt(i) % 256);
                b = (i % 256);
                img.setPixel(x, y, qRgb(r, gr, b));
             }
        }

    //stringstream s;
    //s << fnum;
    //fname= "julia" + s.str();
    //fname+=".png";
    //img.save(fname.c_str(),"PNG", 100);
    img.save("julia.png","PNG", 100);
    cout<< "Finished"<<endl;
    cout<<time.elapsed()/1000.00<<" seconds"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: I think that QImage can not work on several threads at once, you should use a mutex or something similar.

Comment: As a heads up, people generally watch the C++ tag rather than the C++11 tag. You might want to remove one of your tags and replace it with the C++ tag, so more people see your question.

Comment: Consider the scope of your scalar doubles (newRe,OldRe,...). Is it OK that they are being updated concurrenty by many threads? In C/C++ it is generally preferable to declare variables in the minimal required scope...

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in comments, you have two main problems:

- `newRe` and `newIm` are shared, but should not be
- `r`, `gr` and `b`'s access is not specified (shared by default I think)
- There is concurrent calls to `QImage::setPixel`

To correct this, do not hesitate to make a `omp for` loop nested in a `omp parallel` block.

Declare private variable just before the `for` loop:

To prevent concurrent calls to `QImage::setPixel`, [since this function is not thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50366141/1212012), you can put it in a critical region, with `#pragma omp critical`.

---

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int imageWidth=1000, imageHeight=1000, maxIterations=3000;

    double cRe = -0.7;
    double cIm = 0.27015;

    QElapsedTimer time;
    QImage img(imageHeight, imageWidth, QImage::Format_RGB888);//Qimagetesting
    img.fill(Qt::black);
    time.start();

    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        /* all folowing values will be private */
        int i,x,y;
        int r, gr, b;
        double newRe, newIm, oldRe, oldIm;

        #pragma omp for
        for(y = 0; y < imageHeight; y++)
        {            
            for(x = 0; x < imageWidth; x++)
            {
                newRe = newReal(x,imageWidth);
                newIm = newImaginary(y,imageHeight);
                i= julia(newRe, newIm, oldRe, oldIm, cRe, cIm, maxIterations);

                r = (3*i % 256);
                gr = (2*(int)sqrtf(i) % 256);
                b = (i % 256);

                #pragma omp critical
                    img.setPixel(x, y, qRgb(r, gr, b));
             }
        }
    }

    img.save("julia.png","PNG", 100);

    cout<<time.elapsed()/1000.00<<" seconds"<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

To go further, you can save some cpu time replacing `::setPixel` by `::scanLine`:

```
    #pragma omp for
    for(y = 0; y < imageHeight; y++)
    {                        
        uchar *line = img.scanLine(y);
        for(x = 0; x < imageWidth; x++)
        {
            newRe = newReal(x,imageWidth);
            newIm = newImaginary(y,imageHeight);
            i= julia(newRe, newIm, oldRe, oldIm, cRe, cIm, maxIterations);

            r = (3*i % 256);
            gr = (2*(int)sqrtf(i) % 256);
            b = (i % 256);

            *line++ = r;
            *line++ = gr;
            *line++ = b;
         }
    }
```

---

EDIT:

Since the julia set seems to have a central symetry around `(0,0)` point, you can perfom only half of calculus:

```
int half_heigt = imageHeight / 2;
#pragma omp for

// compute only for first half of image
for(y = 0; y < half_heigt; y++)
{            
    for(x = 0; x < imageWidth; x++)
    {
        newRe = newReal(x,imageWidth);
        newIm = newImaginary(y,imageHeight);
        i= julia(newRe, newIm, oldRe, oldIm, cRe, cIm, maxIterations);

        r = (3*i % 256);
        gr = (2*(int)sqrtf(i) % 256);
        b = (i % 256);

        #pragma omp critical
        {
            // set the point  
            img.setPixel(x, y, qRgb(r, gr, b));

            // set the symetric point
            img.setPixel(imageWidth-1-x, imageHeight-1-y, qRgb(r, gr, b));
        }
     }
}
```